# Scroll down refreshes my list from all positions

Tags: listview, android-studio, android-fragments, swiperefreshlayout

I am not able to scroll down after scrolling up in my home fragment.List view has been set swipe down refresh.I need both the swipe down and scroll down in my application but refresh action should only work if the list is at the top.

my home fragment activity

```
     public class EmployerHome extends Fragment implements AbsListView.OnScrollListener {


private ArrayList<Sample> list;
private ConnectAdapter adapter;
private ListView listView;
private HashMap<String, String> cData;
private CardView cv;
private Common mApp;
private Context mContext;
private RelativeLayout udyowel;
private ProgressBar progressBar;

private int preLast;
private SwipeRefreshLayout swipe;

public EmployerHome() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    mContext = getActivity();
    mApp = (Common) mContext.getApplicationContext();
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_employer_home, container, false);

    udyowel = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.udyopro_post);
    listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.post);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
    swipe = (SwipeRefreshLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.swipe);
    cv = (CardView) view.findViewById(R.id.udp);
    list = new ArrayList<Sample>();

    new GetHome(getActivity(), listView, progressBar, mApp.getPreference().getString(Common.u_id, ""), "all", swipe).execute();


   /* if (listView.getCount()==0){
        udyowel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }else {*/
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                TextView txt = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.jId);
                Intent in = new Intent(getActivity(), PostViewActivity.class);
                in.putExtra("jId", txt.getText().toString());
                startActivity(in);
            }
        });
   // }

    listView.setOnScrollListener(this);
    swipe.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            new GetHome(getActivity(), listView, progressBar, mApp.getPreference().getString(Common.u_id, ""), "all", swipe).execute();
        }
    });
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

}

@Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
    if (view.getId() == R.id.post) {
        int lastItem = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount;
        if (lastItem == totalItemCount) {
            if (preLast != lastItem) {
                preLast = lastItem;
                //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "In Last", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        } else {
           // udyowel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
 }
}
```

My xml code

```
   <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/swipe"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.shuan.Project.fragment.ConnectionFragment">


    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/post"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your `onScroll` method, if `firstVisibleItem == 0` set swipe enable otherwise it should remain disable as you should only swipe to refresh if you are on top of the list.

Comment: welcome. you may accept the answer if it helped you  @Nazimch :)